# DB2 can't select a column who contains nullable values

Tags: sql, db2

I have my request where co.DATE_UTILISATION is an integer can be null :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT co.NUMERO) as TOTAL , 
co.DATE_UTILISATION, 
cast(NULL as int) as TEST 
FROM FOIATST.coupons as co 
LEFT OUTER JOIN FOIATST.operateurs as op ON co.OPERATEUR = op.CODE 
WHERE co.SOCIETTE = 999 
AND co.DATE_DEB_VALIDITE = 20131007 AND co.DATE_FIN_VALIDITE = 20140107 
AND co.ETAT = 'UTILISE ' 
AND co.DATE_DEB_VALIDITE is not NULL AND co.DATE_UTILISATION <> 0 
GROUP BY DATE , ETAT
```

i 've tested  cast(NULL as int) as TEST from [DB2: Won't Allow "NULL" column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509233/db2-wont-allow-null-column)

my request works well without "co.DATE_UTILISATION, " can you show me my mistake please ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are grouping by one column but selecting another.

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT co.NUMERO) as TOTAL , 
       co.DATE_UTILISATION, 
       cast(NULL as int) as TEST 
FROM FOIATST.coupons as co 
LEFT OUTER JOIN FOIATST.operateurs as op ON co.OPERATEUR = op.CODE 
WHERE co.SOCIETTE = 999 
AND co.DATE_DEB_VALIDITE = 20131007 AND co.DATE_FIN_VALIDITE = 20140107 
AND co.ETAT = 'UTILISE ' 
AND co.DATE_DEB_VALIDITE is not NULL AND co.DATE_UTILISATION <> 0 
GROUP BY co.DATE_UTILISATION, ETAT;
```

Also, the inclusion of `etat` in `group by` is not necessary, because you are filtering it down to one value anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When using GROUP BY, all columns in your SELECT list must either be aggregate functions or in the GROUP BY clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT co.NUMERO) as TOTAL , 
       co.DATE_UTILISATION, 
       cast(NULL as int) as TEST 
FROM      FOIATST.coupons    co 
LEFT JOIN FOIATST.operateurs op   ON co.OPERATEUR = op.CODE 
WHERE co.SOCIETTE = 999 
  AND co.DATE_DEB_VALIDITE is not NULL
  AND co.DATE_DEB_VALIDITE = 20131007
  AND co.DATE_FIN_VALIDITE = 20140107 
  AND co.ETAT = 'UTILISE ' 
  AND co.DATE_UTILISATION <> 0 
GROUP BY co.DATE_UTILISATION, TEST;
```

But in this query you have given us, there is no usage of columns from the operators table, and since it is a LEFT JOIN, it has no affect on which records are chosen from the coupons table.  Since you are selecting only records where DATE_DEB_VALIDITE = 20131007, then why bother also testing that it is not NULL?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT co.NUMERO) as TOTAL , 
       co.DATE_UTILISATION, 
FROM      FOIATST.coupons    co 
WHERE co.SOCIETTE = 999 
  AND co.DATE_DEB_VALIDITE = 20131007
  AND co.DATE_FIN_VALIDITE = 20140107 
  AND co.ETAT = 'UTILISE ' 
  AND co.DATE_UTILISATION <> 0 
GROUP BY co.DATE_UTILISATION;
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to change

```
co.DATE_UTILISATION, 
cast(NULL as int) as TEST
```

to

```
coalesce(co.DATE_UTILISATION , 0)
```

and also

```
AND co.DATE_DEB_VALIDITE is not NULL AND co.DATE_UTILISATION <> 0
```

to

```
AND co.DATE_DEB_VALIDITE is not NULL AND coalesce(co.DATE_UTILISATION, 0) <> 0
```

Comment: according to E.H `cast(NULL as int)` is not the issue because it works if he leaves out `co.DATE_UTILISATION,`